# Bought a new (old) house and a new subpanel for the pool was installed. No clue if this is safe

Tags: electrical, wiring, subpanel, pool

I bought a house and prior to the sale a subpanel was installed at the pool area.  The home inspector says it’s fine, but he really wasn’t there to make sure things are code compliant. Before I hire someone or try to tackle this myself, i figured I’d start here and see where to go.

Right now, there is a 2-2-2-4 SER cable running from a 100amp 2 pole breaker in the main panel (200amp service) to a huge 12”x12”x6” junction box about 30-35’ away. In the box, the SER cable is split and the wires are joined with insulated Polaris wire joints (Per the inspector) to individual 2 gauge (4 gauge for the ground) THHN wires. The wires then run into a conduit connected to the box across ceiling and exit the house and go into the ground. The conduit runs about 150’ to a subpanel at the pool. The panel has a 2 20amp 2 pole breakers, 1 50amp 2 pole breaker and a 20amp single pole breaker. The breakers are all gfci and run a pump, heater, salt unit and outlet. Everything seems ok, but I thought the wires to the subpanel needed to be be continuous. Is this ok as is or should I consider having continuous wires run for this? I usually do all my own construction work, but other than identifying wiring, I don’t touch it. Sooooo...is this go to go or should I look into redoing it? I’ve never dealt with pools or subpanels before.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the existing wires copper or aluminum?

Comment: Was the work permitted?  Was it signed off by the building inspector?

Comment: Aside from the service coming into the house, all the wiring is copper. As far as I know, no permits have been pulled on this house. Ever.

Answer (score 4):

Junctions, done properly, are both fine and a fact of life; whether feeding a sub-panel or not.

While it's not the way I would have run it (because I've turned into a THHN/THWN and conduit for darn near everything person) nothing you have described sounds incorrect or unsafe. If the huge junction box were tiny there might be a problem, but it's not (you need some room to safely splice wires that fat.)

If you want persnickity opinions on details of the work, post pictures and they will get picked apart if there's anything amiss.